# How to retrieve list of names of board members for a given ticker from Bloomberg Professional

Tags: bloomberg

I would like to investigate some data on individual board members in a systematic way. I have a Bloomberg Terminal at my disposal, which I would like to use for this. In a first step, I need to retrieve a list of all board members for a given company ticker. In a second step, I would then want to retrieve personal-level data for each individual.

Some pointers regarding both steps would be much appreciated. This seems to be a rather specific use case, so I haven't been able to find anything on this online.

Comment: bloomberg have [many](https://www.bloomberg.com/professional/support/api-library/) APIs, which language are you using?

Comment: Excel and Python.

Comment: Have you asked HELP HELP?

Answer (score 1):

For the Excel case, you can use `=BDS("AAPL US Equity","COMPANY_EXEC_OFFICERS")`.

Trying to figure out the Python way to do it, so consider this a bump.

Answer (score 1):

You can install and use the Bloolmberg api in python quite easily. Apart from the Bloomberg terminal software you will have to install the bloomberg api.

Then you can either use the api directly in python by importing it, or, because the api is not so easy to use directly and its kind of verbose, you can use one of the various open source wrappers available of github.

NOTE: this will only work if you are logged in to a the bloomberg terminal so no use trying this if you don't have a login.

Here is an example with `pybbg`:

```
import pybbg
bbg = pybbg.Pybbg()
bbg.bds("AAPL US Equity","COMPANY_EXEC_OFFICERS")
```

With return a pandas dataframe with the data you requested.

[image]